# Using JProfiler on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jetty, jprofiler

I need to profile jetty server on linux system, for it I've started jetty using next command line `JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xrunjprofiler' sh jetty.sh start` and received error **Could not find agent library on the library path or in the local directory: jprofiler**, How can I added library path on linux?
Thanks.

Comment: If you simply use the wizard, it will tell you exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the Jprofiler to the PATH. I hope it works.

Comment: I have executed next command  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/jprofiler6, result the same ... :(

Comment: add this to the environment variables LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Refer to the right library, it matters whether you are using a 64 bit or 32 bit library.

Comment: So I think you should point LD_LIBRARY_PATH to 64 bit library of Jprofiler. http://www.coderanch.com/t/416403/Performance/java/Jprofiler-linux-throwing-error