# Error in starting WebSphere 6.0 with JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler, websphere-6

I want to use JProfiler to profile Websphere v6.0(Java 1.4.2) in a remote server linux(Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 kernel release 2.6.18-238.1.1.el5) but after following the documentation, when I start Websphere, I got the following error:

**JVMCI158: Can't load "libjprofiler.so", because libjprofiler.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
JVMCI098: xmloadJVMHelperLib jprofiler , failed
Could not create the Java virtual machine.**

What I did:

(1)
I add on Application servers > lxvwrap1s1 > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine > Generic JVM arguments:
-Djava.compiler=none -Xrunjprofiler:port=8849 -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/jprofiler7/bin/agent.jar

(2)
I created the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x86

I'm forgetting something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question contains the answer you're looking for: [Using JProfiler on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541857/using-jprofiler-on-linux)

Basically, they suggest you use the Installation Wizard.
Also, they tell you to point the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the 64-bit version of the library.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Is not 64-bit but 32-bit. I solved the problem. 
I edited the file /etc/ld.so.conf and added the directory (/opt/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x86) a new line. 
Exit the command prompt and run ldconfig